# How do I solve $y' = \sin(x - y)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the differential equation:
$$y'=\sin(x-y)$$

Could I do this?

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \sin x \cos y - \sin y \cos x$$

But, how would I continue?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha provides the answers obtained in: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+%3D+sin%28x-y%29

Comment: @Leucippus I found that the general solution is:
$$\tan{(x-y)}+ \sec{(x-y)}=x+c$$

Is this equal to the one that wikipedia provides?

Comment: What is provided from the Wolfram solution is the complete solution of $y(x)$. The solution you have provided, which works, is a mixed solution containing a function of $x$ and $y(x)$. Solving the solution you have provided for $y(x)$ should provide something close to that provided by Wolfram.

Comment: @Leucippus But how can I solve it for $y(x)$ ?

Answer (score 12):

If you substitute $y_1=y-x$ you get:

$$y_1'=y'-1$$

$$\sin(x-y)=\sin(x-y_1-x)=\sin(y_1)$$

So:

$$\sin(y_1)=y_1'+1$$

Next you get $1=\dfrac{y_1'}{\sin(y_1)-1}$ and you can integrate both sides.

You get:

$1)$ Left side: $$\int_{x_0}^{x} 1 dx=x-x_0$$

$2)$Right side (by changing variables): $$\int_{x_0}^{x} \frac{y_1'(x)}{\sin(y_1(x))-1} dx=\int_{y_1(x_0)}^{y(x)} \frac{1}{\sin x-1} dx$$

Comment: Isn't it $\sin(-y_1)=-\sin(y_1)$ ? So,do we have to substitute maybe : $y_1=y-x$ ?

Comment: If $y_1 = y + x$ then $x - y = 2x - y_1$. You should use $y_1 = x-y$...

Comment: So,we do it like that:

$$u=x-y$$

$$u'=1-y'$$

$$1-u'= \sin u \Rightarrow 1- \sin u=u' \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}=1- \sin u \Rightarrow \frac{du}{ 1- \sin u}=dx$$

But how can I continue?

Comment: This solution does not desereve $-2$ as it seems to be true!

Comment: Now it's differential equations by separating variables.

Comment: I have to integrate the relation $\frac{du}{1- \sin u}=dx$,right? But to what is equal the first integral? How can I find it?

Comment: @evinda: set $tan(u/2)=t$ and make the transformation for the integral.

Comment: $\int\frac{1}{1-\sin(u)}du=\int\frac{1+\sin(u)}{\cos^{2}(u)}du=\int\sec^{2}(u)du+\int\tan(u)\sec(u)du$

Comment: Please rewrite your answer. The presentation is awful, which is probably what attracted the down votes.

Comment: @user71352 And can this relation not be simplified?

Comment: It can be but I thought I should let you figure out the last step.

Comment: It is $\int sec^2 u du= \tan u$ . But how can I find the integral $ \int \tan u \sec u du$ ?

Comment: Try differentiating $\sec(u)$.

Comment: Alternatively: $\int\tan(u)\sec(u)du=\int\frac{\sin(u)}{(\cos(u))^{2}}du=-\int\frac{1}{w^{2}}dw$

Comment: So,is the general solution: $\tan(x-y)+ \sec(x-y)=x+c$ ?

Comment: @mesel It is true *now*.  It was wrong at the beginning when it first received the downvotes.  Given that most people won't revisit a question, that $-2$ is probably here to stay (regrettably).

Comment: @anorton: yeah I got it, I think it is good to be patient  for downvoting to give time to fix the answer if he can.

Comment: @mesel Agreed.  (+1 from me, in any event; I wasn't a downvoter, though)

Answer (score 4):

I will only add the solution of the integral,

$$\int\dfrac{1}{1-\sin x}dx$$ set $\tan(x/2)=u$ then you will have

$$\int\dfrac{1}{1-{2u\over{1+u^2}}} \dfrac{2}{u^2+1} du$$

As a result you will have $$\dfrac{2\sin(\dfrac x2)}{\cos(\dfrac x2)-\sin(\dfrac x2)}+c$$

Comment: How do you get from the first integral to the seond one,using the substitution? Do you use a formula?

Comment: @evinda: just the substition,  if $tan(x/2)=u$ then $cos(x/2)=\dfrac {1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$ and  $sin(x/2)=\dfrac {u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$ then use $sin(x)=2sin(x/2)cos(x/2)=\dfrac {2u}{{1+u^2}}$

Comment: A ok..is the general solution $\tan(x-y)+ \sec(x-y)=x+c$,or have I found it wrong?

Comment: It's $\large{2\,{\rm d}u \over 1 + u^{2}}$ in your second line.

Comment: @FelixMarin: thank you for your correction.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found to actually solve the DE is like this:
$$let\ \ u=x-y \iff y=x-u \iff \frac{dy}{dx}=1-\frac{du}{dx}$$
Substituting in:
$$1-\frac{du}{dx}=\sin(u)\\\iff \frac{du}{dx}=1-\sin(u)\\ \iff \frac{1}{1-\sin(u)}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}=1$$
Multiplying throughout with $\frac{1+\sin(u)}{1+\sin(u)}$:
$$\frac{1+\sin(u)}{1-\sin^2(u)} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}=1 \\ \iff \left( \frac{1}{\cos^2(u)}+\frac{\sin(u)}{\cos^2(u)} \right)\cdot\frac{du}{dx}=1\\\iff\left( \sec^2(u)+\sec(u)\tan(u) \right)\cdot\frac{du}{dx}=1$$
This is much easier to integrate. So integrating both sides:
$$\int \left( \sec^2(u)+\sec(u)\tan(u) \right)\cdot\frac{du}{dx} dx=\int dx\\\iff \tan(u)+\sec(u)=x+C$$
And substituting $u=x-y$ back in gives the implicit general solution:
$$\tan(x-y)+\sec(x-y)=x+C$$
I feel this one makes much more sense than doing it through the $z=\tan(\frac{u}{2})$ substitution, which I feel just came from plugging it into wolfram alpha or something similar instead of actually attempting it. Or I could just be missing why the other substitution is more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = x - y$. Thus, $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 1 - \dfrac{dz}{dx}$ and
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \sin(x - y) \quad \Rightarrow \quad \dfrac{dz}{dx} = 1 - \sin z \quad \Rightarrow \quad \int dx = \int \dfrac{dz}{1 -\sin z}
$$
The next step is to change $u = \tan(z/2)$ so that $dz = \dfrac{2du}{1 + u^2}$. Note that
$$
\sin z = \dfrac{2\sin(z/2)\cos(z/2)}{\cos^2(z/2) + \sin^2(z/2)} = \dfrac{2\tan(z/2)}{1 + \tan^2(z/2)} = \dfrac{2u}{1 + u^2}
$$
Thus,
$$
x = \int \dfrac{\dfrac{2du}{1 + u^2}}{1 -\dfrac{2u}{1 + u^2}} =2\int \dfrac{du}{1 + u^2 - 2u} = 2\int \dfrac{du}{(1-u)^2} = -\dfrac{2}{1-u} + C \quad \Rightarrow 
$$
$$
x = \dfrac{2}{\tan(z/2) - 1} + C = \dfrac{2}{\tan\biggl(\dfrac{x - y}{2}\biggr) - 1} + C
$$

Comment: So,is the general solution $\tan(x-y)+ \sec(x-y)=x+c$ ?

Comment: Write $z = x - y$ and proceeds as before.

Comment: Could you explain it further to me? Can we not solve this equation for $y(x)$ ?

Comment: As before, I think the solution that other differential equation can not be explained to x.

Comment: At the book,it is given the differential equaltion $y'=\sin (x-y) \text{ and } y(0)=\pi$ and the solution is $y=x-2 \arctan(x+c) + \frac{\pi}{2}$..How can I conclude to this?

Substituting $x=0$ at the solution that I found, I found that $c=-1$..How could I continue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full solution.

The substitution $z=x-y$ turn the equation separable:

$$
z'=1-\sin(z) \\
\int dx=\int {dz\over 1-\sin(z)}
$$

Factorizing by $(1+\sin(z))$ and using $\tan|\sec$:

$$
\int {(1+\sin(z))dz\over 1-\sin^2(z)}=\int {(1+\sin(z))dz\over \cos^2(z)}=\tan(z)+\sec(z)
$$

Hence:
$$
\tan(z)+\sec(z)=x+c
$$

Replacing $\sec$ and solving for $\tan$
$$
\tan(z)+\sqrt{1+\tan^2(z)}=x+c \\
\tan(z)={(x+c)^2-1\over 2(x+c)}
$$
Thus replacing back:
$$
y=x-\tan^{-1}\left({(x+c)^2-1\over 2(x+c)}\right) \pm k\pi \\
y=x-\tan^{-1}\left({2(x+c)\over 1-(x+c)^2 }\right)-\pi/2 \pm k\pi\\
y=x-2\tan^{-1}(x+c)-\pi/2 \pm k\pi
$$
But, since $\sin(x-y)$ must equal the sign of the derivative of $\tan^{-1}$, only odds $k$ integers will work, $n \in \mathbb N$.
$$
y=x-2\tan^{-1}(x+c)+\pi/2 + 2n\pi
$$